# Capture respective index of same string with multiple occurences using Javascript

Tags: javascript

input

```
Lets go to play football.
I love football.
```

Here, how do I get the respective start and end index of both the first 'football' and the second 'football'?

```
var start_index = input.indexOf('football');
```

This only gives me the index of the first occurence of football .

Answer (score 0):

A good place to find out about these kind of things is the documentation [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

As you can see, this function accepts a second parameter that is used to determine form where to start the search.

That means that you can get the index of the second occurrence like this:

```js
var str = "Lets go to play football.\nI love football.";
var firstIndex = str.indexOf("football");
var secondIndex = str.indexOf("football", firstIndex + 1);

console.log(firstIndex, secondIndex);
```

And to do that for all the occurrences, you can use a loop:

```js
var str = "Lets go to play football.\nI love football.\nI love football.";
var indexes = [];
var latestIndex = -1;

while(true){
    latestIndex = str.indexOf("football", latestIndex + 1);
    if(latestIndex === -1){
       break;
    }
    indexes.push(latestIndex);
}

console.log(indexes);
```

Comment: what if there are 10 occurence of football, do I have to find the index like this every time?

Comment: @SubigyaUpadhyay Usually, when you need to do the same thing multiple times, you use a loop. I will add an example for that.

Answer (score 0):

One option is using [`RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) function:

```
var str = "Lets go to play football.\nI love football.";
var reg = /football/g, indices = [];
while (reg.exec(str) !== null) {
  indices.push(reg.lastIndex - reg.source.length);
}
// indices:
//   Array(2)
//     0: 16
//     1: 33
```

In the above code `str` is the input and `indices` is an array of indices (indexes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function that will find every occurence.

```js
const s = 'Lets go to play football.\n' +
    'I love football.';

const findIndices = (s, word) => {
    let index = -1;
    while(1) {
      index = s.indexOf(word, index + 1);
      if (index === -1) return;
      console.log(index);
  }
};

findIndices(s, 'football');
```